# django - multi autocomplete for array field

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

class AdDO(models.Model):
    ...
    tags_name = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=40,
                           blank=True, null=True),
                           blank=True, null=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    ...
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40, db_index=True)
```

How do multi autocomplete for the field `AdDO.tags_name` from `Tag.name`?
The `AdDO.tags_name` needs to get the character field, for example: "watermelon red, green leaf, black stone" (`Tag.name` values separated by commas)

Comment: I have never seen ArrayField before, but it looks interesting.  Get rid of it.  You probably need it to be a ManyToManyField to the Tag model.

Comment: I do not need referential integrity between tables, so do not use ManyToMany. I just need to adjust the values for `tags_name` of `Tag.name`